# Auto-Hide Side Menu when Logout

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So basically I'm trying to disable the side menu on the login page. I'm doing like this and it's working.

login.page.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.menu.enable(false);
}
```

But when I logout, if I swipe left, the side menu still is avaliable. Logout function:

```
logout(){
    localStorage.clear();
  this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('login');
  }
```

HTML Code:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu>
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>         
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-button (click)="logout()">Sair</ion-button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: Post Your HTML Code

Comment: @arunkumar Just eddited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngOnInit()` hook gets called only once when the component gets loaded.

use `ngOnChanges()` hook or disable menu in logout function.

as you are using ionic framework use `ionViewDidEnter()` hook.

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
     if(...not-logged-in...){
          this.menu.enable(false);
     } else {
          this.menu.enable(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in logout method

```
logout(){
    this.menu.enable(false);
    localStorage.clear();
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('login');
  }
```